# Vitest: using h() function in slots causes "Slot invoked outside of the render function" warning

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vitest

I've been refactoring some old tests to use Vue3 and vitest and I'm getting warnings for tests that use the `h()` function in slots.

The following test will pass:

```
it('my test', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(h(InputComponent, {
        id: 'test',
        label: 'test',
      },
      {
        'my-slot': () => [
          h(ButtonComponent),
          h(ButtonComponent)
        ],
      },
    ));
    expect(wrapper.find('.my-slot-class').exists()).toBe(true); 
});
```

But this test and other tests that use the `h()` function in slots will raise a warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Slot "my-slot" invoked outside of the render function: this will not track dependencies used in the slot. Invoke the slot function inside the render function instead.
```

Any ideas on what's going on here? I've tried not using the `h()` function and the tests don't pass.

Answer (score 1):

Tried locally similar functionality with my own components but with the normal syntax and I didn't get the warning that you describe. Can you try the following?

```js
it('my test', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(InputComponent, {
        attrs /* or props or data */: {
            id: 'test',
            label: 'test',
        },
        slots: {
            'my-slot': () => [h(ButtonComponent), h(ButtonComponent)],
        },
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('.my-slot-class').exists()).toBe(true);
});
```

If this wouldn't work could you provide code for your components and versions of the packages you're using for easier debugging?

Comment: So I tried this syntax and am getting the same warning. I can't provide more than a generalized version of the code unfortunately, as it's proprietary. I am using the latest version of vitest and jsdom.

Comment: you could use dummy slots instead of the render functions, like: `slots: { 'my-slot': '<button class="my-slot-class">Test</button>'},`. Is the warning still persisting that way?

Comment: Interesting. yeah still getting the same warning. I guess that it doesn't have anything to do with the h() function but with an array of multiple slots.

Comment: Do you mean that the warning was gone when you only tried it with one button like my example above? In that case maybe you could try creating or wrapper div for them or just rendering one or handle this test in an e2e test since it sounds like this one would rather belong there.